# Select all in a textbox unless clicked again. c# Confused

Tags: c#, textbox, mousedown, selectall

I'm trying to make it in my program, if you click on a text box it will select it all.  And then if you click it again it deselects it all.

I've tried making it like this..

```
 private void url_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        url.ReadOnly = false;
        url.SelectAll();
        url.DeselectAll();

    }
```

I know the url.DeselectAll(); is in the wrong spot.
Any help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type is "my program"? Asp.net webforms?

Comment: You have your answer right in front of you, the key word `Click` should lead you to which `Event` to put your code. Here is a hint.. if Clicked Keep a `Counter or Boolean`, then `SelectAll` method will be Invoked.. if Clicked again, Check if Clicked is True then InVoke `DeselectAll` Method() and set Boolean back to False does this make sense

Answer (score 0):

Your current code first calls

```
url.SelectAll();
```

and then immediately calls

```
url.DeselectAll();
```

Instead, check the current state of the item you are trying to toggle.  It's not clear to me from the question exactly what that is, so in pseudocode:

```
private bool isSelected = false;

private void url_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    url.ReadOnly = false;
    if (isSelected)
    {
        url.DeselectAll();
    } 
    else 
    {
        url.SelectAll();
    }
    isSelected = !isSelected;
}
```

Replace `IsDeselected` with something that checks whether the current state is deselected or not.

Comment: Updated for the case that only the MouseDown event causes selection to toggle.  Assumes initial state is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the textbox itself clears a selection, so you'd have to do something like this;

```
    bool selected;
    private void url_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        url.ReadOnly = false;
        if (!selected)
        {
            selected = true;
            url.SelectAll();
        }

        else
        {
            selected = false;
            url.DeselectAll();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code always selects and then deselects again, so your text will always be deselected after mouse down.

Try this instead:

```
private void url_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    url.ReadOnly = false;
    if (url.SelectedText.Length < url.Text.Length) {
        url.SelectAll();
    } else {
        url.DeselectAll();
    }
}
```